# popper.js shows up without any style

Tags: popper.js

I'm developing an ASP.net-mvc web-app which will be used locally therefore  it doesn't have access to internet.
I used "popper.js" library ,it works properly but popup's don't have any style ( no background-color , no arrow , .. )

For first time I used nuget PM but it didn't change then
I tried to add "popper.css" manually , in this case if i add "popper" class to reference object , background and corners would show up correctly but arrow still doesn't show up. 
i guess js file can't access to style and image files , it probably have a collection of css and images in structural folders but i don't know how could i find these files and where should i put them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify Popper.js by giving it a modifiers object: https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html#modifiers

To enable arrow you can pass it an object like this:

```
var tooltip = new Tooltip($(this), {
   placement: 'top',
   popperOptions: {
      modifiers: {
         preventOverflow: {
            enabled: false
         },
         arrow: {
            enabled: true,
            element: anchorElement
         }
      }
   }
});
```

The arrow element has to be a DOM element so that the popper knows where to render the arrow.

Comment: do you mean the arrow isn't being created by popper.js ? and i need to create it my-self and then popper.js will show it on the right place

Comment: Yeah I think you have to set an anchor element for the arrow yourself.
[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/poppers-with-arrows) an example I made when creating a custom popper for a React app using Material UI, maybe it'll help